# Do I need junction boxes where conduit containing data cables terminates?

Tags: electrical, wiring, conduit

I'm going to be running 1" blue PVC conduit from all my low voltage boxes to a structured wiring panel. My wiring panel will chase to the attic where necessary and I was wondering what the best practice/code compliant method was for reducing my 1" conduit runs down to the chase. Will I need a junction box somewhere in the attic? Can I just leave the 1" conduits open ended somewhere near the chase(s)?

Comment: What type of conduit?  What do you mean by open ended?  What is this being used for?  Junction boxes/you mean switch?  I am very confused.  We are talking about cable/dish conduit right - otherwise I don't understand what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

I would use boxes or at least caps to prevent insects from using your conduit as an expressway. At worst, you could have water moving down from a leak; at best, you might have cold air moving down.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much code around low voltage wiring. Leaving the conduits open-ended is fine. If you find junction boxes, that would be nice but not required.

Comment: All of chapter 8 of the National Electrical Code is dedicated to communications systems (Article 800, 810, 820, and 830). Also, article 645 deals with Information Technology Equipment. If you're in the US and/or follow NEC, there are plenty of codes to abide by.